# Displaying a TikZ diagram to the right of text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the figure of a rectangle to be displayed to the right of some text describing it.  Currently, the rectangle is mostly above the text (and to the right of it).  I guess that having the top vertex aligned with the top edge of the box containing the text would be appropriate.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{4.75in}
\noindent {\textbf{1.) }}The area of a rectangle is 168 square inches, and its perimeter is 62 inches. What is the product of the magnitudes of its diagonals?
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \hspace{2.5in} \= \kill
\> {\textbf{a.) }}625   \> {\textbf{b.) }}300 \\
\> {\textbf{c.) }}200   \> {\textbf{d.) }}150 \\
\> {\textbf{e.) }}125
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%Vertices A, B, C, and D are located.
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) (20:{7/8}) coordinate (B) ($(B) +(110:3)$) coordinate (C) ($(C) +(-160:{7/8})$) coordinate (D);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

%The diagonals are drawn.
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (C);
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (D);


%The length and width of the rectangle are typeset.
\node[anchor={20+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!1.5mm!-90:(B)$)!0.5!($(B)!1.5mm!90:(A)$)$){$w$};
\node[anchor={110+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!1.5mm!-90:(C)$)!0.5!($(C)!1.5mm!90:(B)$)$){$\ell$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The baseline for the minipage defaults to the center, while the baseline for the tikzpicture defauts to the bottom.  Both can be adjusted.  The simplest solution is to use \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)].  That or \begin{minipage}[b]

Comment: removed `[tex-core]` from the tag list, since the question is definitely about latex.

Comment: @John Kormylo  I am picky.  I would like the top corner of the rectangle to be aligned with the top of `current bounding box`.  For some reason, `current bounding box.north` did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the top of the minipage to the top of the tikzpicture, use:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.75in}
\noindent {\textbf{1.) }}The area of a rectangle is 168 square inches, and its perimeter is 62 inches. What is the product of the magnitudes of its diagonals?
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \hspace{2.5in} \= \kill
\> {\textbf{a.) }}625   \> {\textbf{b.) }}300 \\
\> {\textbf{c.) }}200   \> {\textbf{d.) }}150 \\
\> {\textbf{e.) }}125
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]

%Vertices A, B, C, and D are located.
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) (20:{7/8}) coordinate (B) ($(B) +(110:3)$) coordinate (C) ($(C) +(-160:{7/8})$) coordinate (D);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

%The diagonals are drawn.
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (C);
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (D);


%The length and width of the rectangle are typeset.
\node[anchor={20+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!1.5mm!-90:(B)$)!0.5!($(B)!1.5mm!90:(A)$)$){$w$};
\node[anchor={110+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!1.5mm!-90:(C)$)!0.5!($(C)!1.5mm!90:(B)$)$){$\ell$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: alignment]

---

Actually, that aligns the top of the tikzpicture to the bottom of `1)`.  To align to the top of `1)` add something like

```
\path (current bounding box.north) ++(0,-.6\baselineskip) coordinate (align);
```

and `[baseline=(align)]`  One can also use `\raisebox{0.6\baselineskip}{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

add [b] option in minipage

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{4.75in}
\noindent {\textbf{1.) }}The area of a rectangle is 168 square inches, and its perimeter is 62 inches. What is the product of the magnitudes of its diagonals?
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \hspace{2.5in} \= \kill
\> {\textbf{a.) }}625   \> {\textbf{b.) }}300 \\
\> {\textbf{c.) }}200   \> {\textbf{d.) }}150 \\
\> {\textbf{e.) }}125
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{2in}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%Vertices A, B, C, and D are located.
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) (20:{7/8}) coordinate (B) ($(B) +(110:3)$) coordinate (C) ($(C) +(-160:{7/8})$) coordinate (D);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

%The diagonals are drawn.
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (C);
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (D);


%The length and width of the rectangle are typeset.
\node[anchor={20+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!1.5mm!-90:(B)$)!0.5!($(B)!1.5mm!90:(A)$)$){$w$};
\node[anchor={110+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!1.5mm!-90:(C)$)!0.5!($(C)!1.5mm!90:(B)$)$){$\ell$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

in fact, I do not like these layouts with minipages, so do this directly with tikz by adjusting the position of the nodes

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(fig){\begin{tikzpicture}
%Vertices A, B, C, and D are located.
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) (20:{7/8}) coordinate (B) ($(B) +(110:3)$) coordinate (C) ($(C) +(-160:{7/8})$) coordinate (D);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

%The diagonals are drawn.
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (C);
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (D);


%The length and width of the rectangle are typeset.
\node[anchor={20+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!1.5mm!-90:(B)$)!0.5!($(B)!1.5mm!90:(A)$)$){$w$};
\node[anchor={110+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!1.5mm!-90:(C)$)!0.5!($(C)!1.5mm!90:(B)$)$){$\ell$};

\end{tikzpicture}};
\node[below left =0em of fig.north west, text width=4.75in]{
\noindent {\textbf{1.) }}The area of a rectangle is 168 square inches, and its perimeter is 62 inches. What is the product of the magnitudes of its diagonals?
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \hspace{2.5in} \= \kill
\> {\textbf{a.) }}625   \> {\textbf{b.) }}300 \\
\> {\textbf{c.) }}200   \> {\textbf{d.) }}150 \\
\> {\textbf{e.) }}125
\end{tabbing}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code does not align the top of the `minipage` environment containing the question and the top corner of the rectangle.  Using the option `[t]` for the `minipage` environment containing the question and using the option `[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]` for the `tikzpicture` environment does give me what I want.  (The `tikzpicture` is not put in a `minipage` environment.)